# 2nd bachelors vs 2nd masters

Tags: canada, second-degree

I already have a BS and MS of a certain degree. I am contemplating going for a 2nd BS or 2nd MS, in which my employer is willing to provide financial aid. The employer is generally supportive of me getting a 2nd degree with the belief that I will become a better employee, and I am interested in the fact that I can put it on my resume to potentially be more desirable to companies.

So there is the option to get a BS for this 2nd degree, or skip the BS and go directly for the 2nd MS. I'm not sure which option would benefit me more. I believe I have done enough related real-world work that I could easily stomp out the BS (though it would take longer), or at least not struggle too badly if I skipped the BS and went directly into the MS.

Would an employer see more benefit in having 1 BS and 2 MS, vs 2 BS and 1 MS?

Comment: Have you asked your employer? I believe most employers won't care about a second degree at all.

Comment: Also likely field-dependent. One I was looking at, translation in Canadian universities, has a very practical BA and a more theoretical MA... to the point where the certification for professional work requires that you have the former and the latter was not going to be sufficient. You could email or call a couple department heads and get their opinion; I did this and found them surprisingly eager to clarify the value of the different programs.

Comment: Can you edit to add the lengths of the BS and MS? (Presumably the lengths will be on a part-time basis.)

Answer (score 4):

Ask your employer. They're the ones funding you after all.

Having said that I strongly suspect they'll prefer a 2nd Masters as opposed to 2nd Bachelor's. Several reasons:

- Masters degrees usually take a much shorter time to get.
- You learn more in a Masters. Bachelor's degree are broader in the sense that you often have breadth requirements. You can't focus everything on your major. That doesn't apply to a Masters degree.
- You learn more advanced things in a Masters degree. If you have a Masters in [topic], you are assumed to be qualified for jobs that require a Bachelor's in [topic]. The reverse doesn't hold.
- Holding two Bachelor's degrees is pretty unusual. Why do you need two? Why didn't you do a double major?

Discuss it with your employer, but I strongly suspect they'll prefer a 2nd Masters (they might even be assuming you'll do a 2nd Masters).

Answer (score 2):

In just about every case, it would be better to pursue only the MS degree. Most BS degrees require a large number of preparatory and introductory requirements, with the degree-specific material largely occurring only in the final 1.5 or 2 years in the program.

Do not get a second BS degree after you have already completed an MS degree. While some may question even the wisdom of seeking a second MS degree, if you will receive new training in a field that you have not explored before and you will learn new skills that make you a candidate for different career paths then it may be a reasonable thing to do.